# How to skip Unexpected string errors while testing with mocha

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js, extendscript

I am trying to test an [adobe ExtendScript](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/scripting/pdfs/javascript_tools_guide.pdf) file with Mocha. Mocha is all setup and works fine but stops when it encounters non-valid javascript characters.

The problem is, Extendscript uses a custom syntax to import files: `#include "path/to/file.jsx"` and to target a specific application: `#target "aftereffects"`.

When I try running mocha I receive a `SyntaxError: Unexpected string` error on these lines.

Is there a flag or a way to tell mocha I want it to skip those lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no flag to tall Mocha to ignore such lines. Some options that come to mind:

1. Use a build system like [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) to generate pure JS files from your ExtendScript files, and then have Mocha run on result of the transformation.
2. Hook into the `--compilers` option. You would have to register an ExtendScript compiler with Node.js or create your own fake compiler that just strips out the `#include` directives and register this compiler with Node.js. A good example of how to register such compiler is provided by [CoffeeScript](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/blob/master/lib/coffee-script/register.js).

I think the first method would be safest because looking at Node.js' documentation, I see that the way CoffeeScript register's itself is [marked "deprecated"](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_require_extensions).